# Using 3rd Party Libraries in Python

Tags: python, setup.py, python-imaging-library

I'm currently writing a simple Python (2.7) program using the [Python Image Library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). How can I make my program portable, so that I can run in on another computer (that doesn't already have PIL installed).

I've looked into creating a setup.py file, but I'm not sure this is on the right track.

Comment: This depends a lot on your targeted platform, and what you want your installation story to look like. setup.py can be used to specify dependencies, but it's really for distributing things to other developers; your users will need to run 'python setup.py install', and that will in turn download & install PIL. But if you're trying to distribute a single file with all your dependencies, it gets a lot more complicated (eg, you'll basically be distributing a copy of the Python interpreter and the stdlib, plus your program, plus any dependencies).

Comment: what operating system? if it is some linux, you might want to create a package and let the distro's package manager take care of the dependencies.

Comment: Ideally Windows (7) and Ubuntu, thought if that's too ambitious I'd settle for one or the other

Comment: @AdamKG - I'd happily settle for having users run 'python setup.py install'. I can't figure out how to format the setup.py file to have it install PIL though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, sounds like setup.py is the right way to go here - you should already have a setup() function in it, add an install_requires entry like so:

```
setup(
    name="mypkg", version="0.0.1",
    # etc etc blah blah blabh
    install_requires=["PIL"],
)
```

That should do it! When your users run setup.py install, it will download PIL & run PIL's own installation routine.

Comment: Man, is that all there is to it? I'll test this when I get to a workstation, but for now, thanks for the answer

Comment: This gives me `USER WARNING: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'`

Comment: Is your setup() from distutils or setuptools? It should be setuptools. Can you also check your setuptools version with `import setuptools; setuptools.__version__`?